# Viewstack with components; wait component to load

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm having a viewstack with a few components.
Those components have to execute a function with parameters coming from other components.
Therefore the other component may not me loaded directly.

Is there any way to load a component via AS3 with a function?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eterps details how to add child components at run time.  If you've specified your child components in MXML, you have a few options for creation:

- use `creationPolicy=auto` -- the engine decides when components are instantiated
- use `creationPolicy=all` -- everything is instantiated at startup
- use `creationPolicy=auto` or `none`, but manually instantiate children when needed.  See: [creating deferred components](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7aee.html)

Since `auto` isn't working for you, I'd try `all`.  Only if that instantiates too much too soon would I delve into deferred components.

Answer (score 0):

Any MXML component can be instantiated via AS3.  You can use the creationComplete event to call a method that creates your components and adds them to the display list.  See the example below, which creates a button and HGroup in AS3, then makes the button a child of the HGroup, and the Hgroup a child of the panel.

```
    <s:Panel creationComplete="createButtonComponent(event)">
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.Button;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        import spark.components.HGroup;


        protected function buttonClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // Do something
        }

        protected function createButtonComponent(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            var group:HGroup = new HGroup();
            group.percentHeight = 20;
            group.percentWidth = 100;

            var myButton:Button = new Button();
            myButton.label = 'My Button';
            myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler);

            group.addElement(myButton);
            this.addElement(group);
        }

    ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    </s:Panel>
```

This code above is similar to the following MXML:

```
<s:Panel creationComplete="createButtonComponent(event)">
  <s:HGroup id="group" height="20%" width="100%">
    <mx:Button id="myButton" label="My Button" click="buttonClickHandler" />
  </s:HGroup>
</s:Panel>
```